# How to type custom widget for Algolia React instant search?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, algolia, react-instantsearch

I'm trying to correctly type my connected list of Hits from algolia instant search.

My custom Hits component:

```
type Props = { hits: User[]; onSelectUser: (user: User) => void };

const SearchResults: React.FC<Props> = ({ hits, onSelectUser }) => {
  return hits.map((hit: User) => (
    <UserCard user={hit} onSelectUser={onSelectUser} />
  ));
};

export default connectHits<Props>(SearchResults);
```

When I try to use the component:

```
<Hits hitComponent={() => (<SearchResults onSelectUser={setSelectedUser} />)}/>
```

I get a TS error that onSelectUser does not exist on that component... When I ignore this TS error I see that the props are available within in the SearchResults component.

How should I type my component correctly to ensure that the typings are still working correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extend the `HitsProvided` interface exposed by `react-instantsearch-core`.

```
import { HitsProvided } from "react-instantsearch-core";

// ...

type Props = HitsProvided<UserRecord> & {
  onSelectUser: (user: User) => void;
};

const SearchResults: React.FC<Props> = ({ hits, onSelectUser }) => {
  return hits.map((hit: User) => (
    <UserCard user={hit} onSelectUser={onSelectUser} />
  ));
};

export default connectHits<Props, UserRecord>(SearchResults);
```

`UserRecord` would describe the shape of your record (not the shape of the hit returned by the API, only the attributes).